# What options do I have for storing data without using Sql?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I store data (for example: Config file) in MVC *without using Sql*, when im using third-party class, when I have no access to the Server proparty?

I want the data to remain in a subdirectory of the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any format you like for the files: XML, JSON, ... whatever you feel comfortable with. There are serializers built directly into the framework which will allow you to directly serialize/deserialize your objects into those formats.

Just one thing to bare in mind if you decide to go that route: multithreading. Make sure that you properly synchronize the access to this file or you could get corrupted data if you have concurrent readers and writers. Think for example user A saving his settings (and thus writing to the file) while User B is reading his settings => you will end up with corruption. One technique to properly synchronize access to such shared resource is to use the [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I store the data (or the file) in the website folder?

Comment: @Exsaliver, you could use the Server.MapPath method which will give you the absolute path to the application folder. For example `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/myfile.xml")` will return `c:\wwwroot\mysite\App_Data\myfile.xml` so that you can work with the file.

Comment: I have no access to Server Prop, i'm using outside class.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is store a config file, why not keep it in the web.config?  Any class library you reference which requires its own configuration from a .config file will look in your app's web.config.